# Generate serial number using letters and digits

Tags: c#, uniqueidentifier, autonumber

I'm developing an application for taking orders in C# and DevExpress, and I need a function that generates a unique order number. The order number must contain letters and digits and has a length of 20 ..
I've seen things like Guid.NewGuid() but I don't want it to be totally random, nor to be just an auto increment number ..

Can anyone help? even if it's a script in a different language, I need ideas desperately :)

Comment: If you don't want it to be random, how do you want it?

Comment: `Guid.NewGuid()` is unique. Not random.

Comment: something like an auto incremented string , hexadecimal numbers, .. things that reflect the order between numbers (ord1 is before ord2 and so on ..)

Comment: Order numbers best be tracked by incrementing numbers, what are you looking for. Give a few examples.

Comment: I'm thinking about taking the primary key which is an auto number, pad it with zeros until the length becomes 20 .. but this way I'm limiting the order number to be made of digits only ..

Answer (score 1):

You can create type of your own . 
lets say yyyyMMddWWW-YYY-XXXXXXX    where WWW is the store number, YYY the cashier id  XXXXXXX is a hexadecimal number ( -> maybe an actual autoincrement number that you turn it into hex ) . This is just an idea . Im afraid you have to decide by the elements of your system how it will be .

edited : also if you can apply a check digit algorithm on it will also help in avoiding mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Two different methods:

- Create MD5 or SHA1 hash of current time
- Hash of increment number

Comment: But the current time is (Thought some collissions) You could use a more roboust hasing algoritm such as SHA256

Answer (score 0):

Like Oded suggested, Guid is not random (well, not if you have a network card). It's based on time and location coordinates. See [Raymond Chens blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx) for a detailed explanation.
You are best off using an auto incremented int for order ids. I don't understand why you wouldn't want to use it or failing that a Guid?

I can't think of any way other then an auto id to maintain uniqueness and represent the order of your different orders in your system.

Answer (score 0):

One thought comes to mind. 
Take the DateTime.Now.Ticks convert it to hexadecimal string.
Voila, `String.Format("{0:X}", value);`

If not long enough , you said you need 20 digits, you can always pad with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the mother board ID
2. Get the hdd ID
3. Merge it by any way
4. Add your secret code
5. Apply MD5
6. Apply Base54

Result: the serial code which is linked to the currect client PC :)

Answer (score 0):

My two cents.

If you need ideas then take a look at the [Luhn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) and [Luhn mod N](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_mod_N_algorithm) algorithms.

While these algorithms are not unique code generators, they may give you some ideas on how to generate codes that can be validated (such that you could validate the code for correctness before sending it off to the database).